# Show that the two estimators are unbiased for $\theta$

Tags: unbiased-estimator, estimators

$X_1$ and $X_2$, one accurate than the other, are subject to the standard deviations, $\sigma$ and 1.25$\sigma$
respectively. $X_1$ occurred 6 independent times, giving a mean of
$\bar{x}_1$ while $X_2$ occurred 10 independent times with a mean of $\bar{x}_2$ Suppose
the two samples are drawn form a population with mean, $\theta$ and variance, $\sigma^2$

How is it shown that the two estimators are unbiased for $\theta$, and also which estimator will be preferred if I have to choose between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if an estimator, $\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased for $\theta$ you need to calculate the bias:

$$b = bias(\theta) = E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta $$

If $b=0$ then the estimator is unbiased. If the bias is not zero then the estimator is biased. The bias assesses how close an estimate of $\theta$ is to $\theta$ on average.

If two estimates are unbiased then the one with least variance is preferred, this is because if it has less variance then it should, on average, be closer to $\theta$.

Now the variance of a mean, $\bar{x}$ based on a sample of size $n$  is

$$Var(\bar{X})  = Var(X)/n $$

when each  $X$ is independent.

Therefore,

$$Var(\bar{X}_1) =\frac{\sigma^2}{6} \approx 1.67\sigma^2$$
$$Var(\bar{X}_2) =\frac{1.25^2 \sigma^2}{10} \approx 1.56\sigma^2$$

So the second estimator has least variance, thus is preferred.

Comment: @BruceET On the contrary, often in the design of experiments or monitoring programs one has the option of taking more cheaper samples or fewer expensive samples for a given budget and, typically, the cheaper ones are less precise.  This textbook question captures the essence of the tradeoff between cost (that is, numerousness) and precision (that is, the reciprocal of the variance).

Comment: @whuber. Granted that. But to answer helpfully, it would be nice to have an explicit statement whether the 'estimators' being compared are $X_1$ vs. $X_2$ or $\bar X_1$ based on $n=6$ vs. $\bar X_2$ based on $n=10.$

Comment: @Bruce In the context, the bars look clear enough to me.  Indeed, apart from the issue of whether we choose to use $\bar x_1$ or $\bar X_1,$ *etc.,* everything is quite well defined within the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

$$
E \bar{x}_1 = E[\frac{1}{6}\sum X_1^j] = 
\frac{1}{6} 6 E[X_1] = E[X_1],
$$
and in the same way,
$$
E \bar{X}_2 = E[\frac{1}{10}\sum X^j_2] = 
\frac{1}{10} 10 E[X_2] = E[X_2].
$$

Since the expectation of the estimators are equal to the expected value, they are unbiased.

Further
$$
V[\frac{1}{6}\sum X^j_1] = \sigma^2\frac{1}{6} > V[\frac{1}{10}\sum X^j_2] = \sigma^2\frac{1.25^2}{10}
$$
So the second estimator has lower variance and is preferred.

Comment: One way to establish unbiasedness. But does not address the issue whether estimator $X_1$ is preferable to estimator $X_2.$

Answer (score 0):

If you have two unbiased estimators $\hat \theta$ and $\tilde \theta$ and they have different variances, then it is ordinarily preferable to use the one with the smaller variance. However, if one estimate is cheaper to obtain or easier to use, you might
use the one with the larger variance, as in @whuber's comment.

*Practical example:* Two unbiased estimators for the mean $\mu$ of a normal
population are the sample mean $A$ and the sample median $H.$ ([See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119414/prove-that-the-sample-median-is-an-unbiased-estimator) for unbiased of the sample median of normal data.)
That is, $E(A) = E(H) = \mu.$ But in any one situation $Var(A) < Var(H),$
so it the sample mean is the preferable estimator.

If
we are trying to estimate $\mu$ with $n = 10$ observations from a normal population with $\sigma=1,$ then
$Var(A_{10}) = 0.1$ and $Var(H_{10}) \approx 0.138.$
So if we were to insist on using the median rather than the mean
we would have to use more than ten observations to get the same degree
of precision of estimation we could get from the mean.

```
set.seed(2020)
h = replicate(10^6, median(rnorm(10)))
mean(h);  var(h)
[1] 0.000159509   # aprx E(H) = 0
[1] 0.1384345     # aprx Var(H) > 0.1
```

In particular, if we had an important practical reason to prefer using the median,
then we could do about as well using the median with $n = 16$
observations as using the mean with 10 observations.

```
h = replicate(10^6, median(rnorm(16)))
mean(h);  var(h)
[1] -9.955106e-05
[1] 0.09042668
```